# How can I create buttons group with bordered container which the buttons should overlay, the containers border should still be seen

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have difficulties creating buttons group inside of container.
The container should have border and the buttons should overlay the container.
The containers border should still be seen, the when the button active its background should make the container invisible. see example;

[I want to implement this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAPF8.png)

I use React, lets just suppose I want to achieve it using simple css and html.

Comment: Without simple HTML/CSS, you'll get less response. Nobody wants to run React to write some CSS. As a matter of helping you, you can check how it's done by [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/button-group/)

Comment: Its not what I look for, my border should be grey and blue only if active..

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried yet?

Comment: @himanshu I can, but I did it with React, and I'm not sure you want to run it for helping me..

Comment: If you scroll down the page on the bootstrap doc, you'll get an example with Radio buttons looking exactly how you want it...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.